# How can I sort a column horizontally into transposed rows with matching prefixes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet column with data that looks like this. ID numbers with count suffixes. How can I transpose them horizontally into rows on a sheet sorted/grouped/filtered by their ID number into the appropriate number of columns matching their suffix number?

Sheet Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wq3Zrh5wE_IHP2utvMeFRHrMe1qra2ppq_G7PrSt-jY/edit?usp=sharing

| What I have |
| --- |
| INV46673-1 |
| INV46673-2 |
| INV56184-1 |
| INV56184-2 |
| INV56184-3 |
| INV56184-4 |
| INV56184-5 |
| INV68328-1 |
| INV68328-2 |
| INV68328-3 |
| INV68328-4 |
| INV68347-1 |
| INV68347-2 |
| INV68347-3 |

| What I need |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INV46673-1 | INV46673-2 |  |  |  |
| INV56184-1 | INV56184-2 | INV56184-3 | INV56184-4 | INV56184-5 |
| INV68328-1 | INV68328-2 | INV68328-3 | INV68328-4 |  |
| INV68347-1 | INV68347-2 | INV68347-3 |  |  |

If sheets has an off the shelf function for this I have not been able to find it. I have tried pivot tables, Hlookup, filtered arrays etc. I am grateful for any advice I may receive. A solution that uses a fixed character count (8) will work but I would love to see something that actually uses the exact ID number.

Comment: One possibility is Edit:Paste.Special:Transpose. Otherwise look on here for q&a with formulae showing a transpose method.

Comment: Sorry just a mistake, has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(BYROW(UNIQUE(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A15,"-"),,1)),LAMBDA(x,JOIN("|",SORT(FILTER(A2:A15,INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A15,"-"),,1)=x))))),"|"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
=index(let(a,regexextract(A2:index(A:A,counta(A:A)),"(.*)-(\d+)"),b,unique(index(a,,1)),c,max(--index(a,,2)),makearray(counta(b),c,lambda(r,x,xlookup(index(b,r)&"-"&index(sequence(1,c),,x),A:A,A:A,)))))
```

[image]